# Why does pandas DataFrame convert integer to object like this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: convert to object automatically]

I am using *value_counts()* to get the frequency for *sec_id*. The output of *value_counts()* should be integers.

When I build DataFrame with these integers, I found those columns are object dtype. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Did you check the type of `df_pos_0219['sec_id']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the object dtype because your `sec_id` column contains string values (e.g. `"94114G"`). When you call `.values` on the dataframe created by `.reset_index()`, you get two arrays which both contain string objects.

More importantly, I think you are doing some unnecessary work. Try this:

```py
>>> sec_count_df = df['sec_id'].value_counts().rename_axis("sec_id").rename("count").reset_index()
```